# How to provide name in kubectl set image

Tags: bash, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm unable to deploy a new image to my service.  I'm trying to run this command in my CI environment:

```
$ kubectl set image deployment/dev2 \
  dev2=gcr.io/at-dev-253223/dev@sha256:3c6bc55e279549a431a9e2a316a5cddc44108d9d439781855a3a8176177630f0
```

I get `unable to find container named "dev2"`

I'll upload my registry and pods and services, not sure why I can't just pass the new image.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dev2-6fdf8d4fb5-hnrnv   1/1     Running   0          7h19m

$ kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
dev2         LoadBalancer   hidden         hidden         80:32594/TCP   6h55m
kubernetes   ClusterIP      hidden         <none>         443/TCP        2d3h
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please show the result of `kubectl get deployment/dev2 -ojsonpath="{.spec.template.spec.containers[*].name}"`

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta just says 661d1a428298276f69028b3e8e2fd9a8c1690095

Comment: That’s very shocking. How did you deploy this thing in the first place? Can you share `kubectl get deploy/dev2 -oyaml`?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta I'm doing this in a CI env. perhaps I named the container my commit name. If i need the previous name to update the image how do i get that or how do i keep it consistent. i just want to send the new image to my deployment

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta can i rename this container in the shell

Answer (score 1):

To get past the particular problem you're seeing, you need to do:

```
$ kubectl set image deployment/dev2 \
  661d1a428298276f69028b3e8e2fd9a8c1690095=gcr.io/at-dev-253223/dev@sha256:3c6bc55e279549a431a9e2a316a5cddc44108d9d439781855a3a8176177630f0
```

instead of

```
$ kubectl set image deployment/dev2 \
  dev2=gcr.io/at-dev-253223/dev@sha256:3c6bc55e279549a431a9e2a316a5cddc44108d9d439781855a3a8176177630f0
```

A Deployment consists of multiple replicas of the same Pod template. A Pod can have many containers, so if you're trying to set the image, you have to specify which container's image you want to set. You only have one container, and surprisingly its name is `661d1a428298276f69028b3e8e2fd9a8c1690095`, so that's what has to go in front of the `=` sign.

That will fix the `unable to find container named "dev2"` error. I have some doubt that the image you're setting it to is correct. The current image being used is:

```
gcr.io/at-dev-253223/661...095@sha256:0fd...20a
```

You're trying to set it to:

```
gcr.io/at-dev-253223/dev@sha256:3c6...0f0
```

The general pattern is:

```
[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]@[IMAGE_DIGEST]
```

(see [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview#registry_name)). This means you're not just taking a new digest of a given image, but changing the image entirely from `661d1a428298276f69028b3e8e2fd9a8c1690095` to `dev`. You will have to decide for yourself that's actually what you intend to do or not.

Answer (score 0):

Describe your pod with `kubectl describe pod dev2-6fdf8d4fb5-hnrnv` and make sure that the name of the container is indeed named `dev2`